# Cannot install programs

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, debian, apt

I noticed today that several packages were missing from the Raspbian repositories (I'm on Raspbian Jessie, and I used `sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade` before everything).

What is this problem, why is it occurring and how to fix it?

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install motion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package motion
```

I also tried this with other packages.

---

**/etc/apt/sources.list:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

---

**`apt search motion`**:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt search motion
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
fonts-ipafont-nonfree-jisx0208/stable 1:00103-3 all
  Japanese TrueType font, IPAfont (JISX0208)

fonts-roboto/unknown,now 1:4.4.4r2-6+rpi1 all [installed,automatic]
  sans-serif font family released with Android Ice Cream Sandwich

libopencv-calib3d2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Camera Calibration library

libopencv-contrib2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision contrib library

libopencv-core2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision core library

libopencv-features2d2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library

libopencv-flann2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library

libopencv-highgui2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library

libopencv-imgproc2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Image Processing library

libopencv-legacy2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision legacy library

libopencv-ml2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Machine Learning library

libopencv-objdetect2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Object Detection library

libopencv-video2.4/now 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,local]
  computer vision Video analysis library

vdpau-va-driver/now 0.7.4-3 armhf [installed,local]
  VDPAU-based backend for VA API
```

Comment: Something is wrong -- from here `apt search motion` includes `motion/stable 3.2.12+git20140228-4+b2 armhf`.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Edited and included /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: Did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` finish without errors?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yeah,, it completed successfully.

Comment: What you observe (update without errors, but existing package not present) is highly unlikely. Are you sure you didn't make a typo somewhere, or overlooked an error message? Otherwise, I'm inclined to say your `/var/lib/dpkg` folder is corrupt.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yeah i'm sure about the error messages. Got any ideas?

Comment: Try making a filesystem check: it's a long shot but I don't have better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `apt-get` on your system is in a confused state for some reason. I'd run `fsck -n /dev/mmcblk0p1` (assuming that's your root device) to see if the filesystem isn't damaged. If the filesystem is OK, I'd remove files used by `apt` and start from scratch:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install motion
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. I am scheduled to submit my project tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the whole [mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website#mirror_site) handling thing works with Debian/Raspbian/apt.  The HTTP based "mirrordirector.raspian.org" [repository is browsable](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/) and seems the same as [archive.raspbian.org](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/). However, in the past I have noticed occasionally that packages available via `apt` aren't there, so possibly there is no master repo and some things may only be on some mirrors, etc.

Anyway, `motion` is in both of those if you click through `main/m` and search down. To save you some time [here it is](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/motion/); the packages you are interested in have `armhf.deb` at the end.  There are three versions there; presumably `4.0-1` is Raspbian testing ("stretch") and 3.2.12 is for jessie; the one that showed up via search for me is [this one](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/motion/motion_3.2.12%2bgit20140228-4%2bb2_armhf.deb), which is ~18 months newer than the other 3.2.12 package.

You can download that and try to install it directly:

```
sudo dkpg -i motion_3.2.12+git20140228-4+b2_armhf.deb
```

This will fail if dependencies are missing, but it should tell you what they are and you can go through the list manually.  It should not be very hard.